# Initializing a SQLAlchemy model instance with its relationship as a parameter

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relationship

I often see, that the model instance with one-to-many relationship is explicitly extended following its initialization, such as:

```
one = One()
# some code goes here
one.many = [Many(), Many(), Many()]
one.many.append(Many())
```

But in my case I see it reasonable to initialize a many-to-one object with it's relationship already supplied to `__init__`:

```
one = One()
many = Many(one = one)
```

**Is it somehow considered a bad practice?**

---

For a reproducible example, please consider the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class One(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'one'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    many = relationship("Many", back_populates="one")


class Many(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'many'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    one_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('one.id'))
    one = relationship("One", back_populates="many")

    def __init__(self, one=None):
        if one is not None:
            self.one = one


# Setup the DB and connection
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
conn = engine.connect()
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Is it proper to initialize a model instance, with its relationship as an argument?
one1 = One()
many1 = Many(one1)
print(many1.one is one1)  # True
print(one1.many[0] is many1)  # True
```

---

**Although it looks clean to me so far, this approach may result in an ambiguous code:**

```
# What happens here?
# Instance of many first initialized with one2a,
# then reassigned to one2b?
one2a = One()
many2 = Many(one=one2a)
print(many2.one is one2a)  # True

one2b = One(many=[many2])  # same when One(many=[Many(one=one2a)])
print(many2 is one2b.many[0])  # True
print(many2.one is one2a)  # False
print(many2.one is one2b)  # True
```

---

Finally, please consider the aforementioned `__init__` method. **Since `self.many` is by default expected to be an empty list, what would be the desired way to initialize it as such?**

```
    def __init__(self, many=None):
        if many is not None:
            self.many = many
```